# Checking on a column for an empty value

Tags: sql, oracle

Please tell me how to write the following algorithm.
Filter by the same "clusterid" which "is not null".

1. If "issuedate" is an empty column, then take "publid", which has more "inn".
2. If "issuedate" is not all equal, then we take "issuedate" = last date.
3. If "issuedate" are all equal, then we take "operdate" = last date.
4. If "issuedate" are equal and operdate are equal, then we take "publid", which has more "inn".

Here's what I got, conditions 2,3,4 are fulfilled here. But I don’t know how to insert 1 condition into the code.

```html
SELECT m.* 
FROM (SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by clusterid, inn order by cnt desc) rn
   FROM (SELECT b.* ,COUNT(inn) OVER (PARTITION BY publid) cnt 
   FROM (SELECT c.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY clusterid order by issuedate desc,operdate desc) rnk
       FROM table as c
       WHERE clusterid is not null) as b
WHERE b.rnk=1) as a
 ) as m 
WHERE m.rn=1
```

I thought maybe through "case when", but I don't know how to do it correctly. I would be grateful if you could help.

```html
SELECT m.* 
FROM (SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by clusterid, inn order by cnt desc) rn
   FROM (SELECT b.* ,COUNT(inn) OVER (PARTITION BY publid) cnt 
       FROM (SELECT c.*, CASE WHEN issuedate='' then OVER (PARTITION BY clusterid)
       else RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY clusterid order by issuedate desc,operdate desc) 
       end rnk
           FROM table as c
           WHERE clusterid is not null) as b
WHERE b.rnk=1) as a
 ) as m 
WHERE m.rn=1
```

Example

```
|*inn*|*publid*|*clusterid*|*issuedate*|*operdate*|
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 333 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 333 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 | -condition 3
| 222 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 111 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 123 |   1    |     1     |  01-01-21 |          |
| 456 |   1    |     1     |  01-01-21 |          |
| 123 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
| 456 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          | - condition 4
| 789 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
| 123 |   3    |     1     |  02-01-21 |          |
| 456 |   3    |     1     |  02-01-21 |          |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 123 |   1    |     1     |           | 01-01-21 |
| 456 |   1    |     1     |           | 01-01-21 |
| 123 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
| 456 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 | - condition 1
| 789 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
| 123 |   3    |     1     |           | 02-01-21 |
| 456 |   3    |     1     |           | 02-01-21 |
```

Result

```
|*inn*|*publid*|*clusterid*|*issuedate*|*operdate*|
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 333 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |- condition 2
| 111 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 123 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
| 456 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |- condition 3
| 789 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 123 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
| 456 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |- condition 1
| 789 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
```

Comment: Using `as` before a table/subquery alias is invalid syntax in Oracle.

Comment: Your snippets don't work. That's because the snippet feature only supports HTML/CSS/JavaScript. And if it did support database code, it would need a complete test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want something like:

```sql
SELECT inn,
       publid,
       clusterid,
       issuedate,
       operdate
FROM   (
  SELECT inn,
         publid,
         clusterid,
         issuedate,
         operdate,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY clusterid
           ORDER     BY issuedate DESC NULLS LAST,
                        CASE WHEN issuedate IS NULL THEN inn END DESC,
                        operdate DESC NULLS LAST,
                        cnt DESC
         ) AS rnk
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           COUNT(inn) OVER (PARTITION BY publid) cnt
    FROM   table_name t
    WHERE  clusterid is not null
  )
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (inn, publid, clusterid, issuedate, operdate ) AS
SELECT 333, 1, 12, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 222, 1, 12, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 333, 2, 12, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 222, 2, 12, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 2, 12, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 1,  1, DATE '2021-01-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 1,  1, DATE '2021-01-01', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 2,  1, DATE '2021-01-03', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 2,  1, DATE '2021-01-03', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, 2,  1, DATE '2021-01-03', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 3,  1, DATE '2021-01-02', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 3,  1, DATE '2021-01-02', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | INN | PUBLID | CLUSTERID | ISSUEDATE | OPERDATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123 | 2 | 1 | 03-JAN-21 |  |
> | 789 | 2 | 1 | 03-JAN-21 |  |
> | 456 | 2 | 1 | 03-JAN-21 |  |
> | 111 | 2 | 12 | 01-JAN-21 | 05-JAN-21 |
> | 333 | 2 | 12 | 01-JAN-21 | 05-JAN-21 |
> | 222 | 2 | 12 | 01-JAN-21 | 05-JAN-21 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=00bdd13ca66d02ec2fc7f7dfd1118a3d)*

---

### Update

```sql
SELECT inn,
       publid,
       clusterid,
       issuedate,
       operdate
FROM   (
  SELECT inn,
         publid,
         clusterid,
         issuedate,
         operdate,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY clusterid
           ORDER     BY COALESCE( issuedate, operdate ) DESC NULLS LAST,
                        cnt DESC
         ) AS rnk
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           COUNT(inn) OVER (PARTITION BY publid) cnt
    FROM   table_name t
    WHERE  clusterid is not null
  )
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1ff732df655b048f2ac3220789b26bb)*

Comment: I need to select not only the first entry that meets the conditions. There can be several of them, so I used rank () over (....), count (inn) over (.....), row_number over (....). The situation may be as follows, added an example to the question now. Look, please, if there is an idea, write.

Comment: Sorry, condition 1 still doesn't work. Conditions 2,3,4 are fulfilled. Thank you very much for your help, if it's not difficult, you can correct the code in accordance with the example that I have added to the question now.

Comment: Good afternoon! Now I need to implement this code in hive, but NULLS LAST does not work in hive. Do you know how you can write this expression differently?

Comment: @lisam You should ask a new question as I do not know the syntax for hive and cannot help you.

Comment: Good day! I need unique inn + publ_id, but I can't write distinct before inn, right?
SELECT t. *, COUNT (DISTINCT inn) OVER (PARTITION BY publid) cnt FROM table_name t
Tell me how you can select unique strings